# having a page in multi sub-menu and match current-menu-item

Tags: menus, sub-menu

On a website I develop, some pages are in several sub-menus, like so:

```
home | product category a | products category b
       * product a          * product c
       * product b          * product b --> same as in previous menu
```

Now how do I get WordPress to add `current-menu-item` and `current-menu-parent` classes to "products category b" and "page b" instead of "product b" in the "product category a".

Currently, it seems that WordPress matches the entries in menu on a first encountered basis. So the entry in that appears first in the menu always takes precedence.

Instead I'd need WordPress to consider what was actually clicked.

So far, the easiest option I have found (no code changes required) is to add a parameter to the url to match a specific menu.

"page b" in "products category b" has its url appended with `?cat=b`. This way, the url is unique to a menu and WP matches it right.

Nevertheless, it's not ideal for SEO and caching. I am therefore still looking for a better solution.

Comment: In order for it to do this, it would need to know where the user clicked and transfer that information across, then modify how the menu is rendered, which doesn't always make sense. For example, if the user gets sent the URL of that page, and loads it directly, which menu will WP declare is the current? How will it tell that apart from if somebody clicked in the nav menu? Keep in mind it will be impossible to use any kind of page cache on your site for this to work. Also, I don't see how changing this will improve SEO, the active menu is just a CSS class, it has no semantic meaning

Comment: Also, there are other classes further up that indicate ancestors all the way up to the root. Remember, HTTP is a stateless protocol, and visiting a URL should always give the same result no matter how you got there. Keeping in mind that in order for the Google bot to see this page both ways it would need to be considered as 2 canonically different URLs, incurring a duplication penalty

Comment: It will not improve SEO, what I meant is that having different URLs or query params is not great for SEO. It would have a default behaviour when accessed directly. Exactly the same way breadcrumbs are managed when there is more than one path to a page.

Comment: You may append some # fragment instead of additional query params. I may be wrong but I think fragments are more SEO friendly (url still considered the same page).

Comment: Really good idea SEO-wise, unfortunately, WP doesn't consider it as a proper URL either and thus doesn't take it into account. I think I'm stuck with my query params…

Comment: Finally sorted it out. Yoast SEO [automatically specifies](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/canonical-urls-in-wordpress-seo/) a meta canonical with a parameter-free url. Alternatively, that's also doable w/o Yoast in pure PHP either by adding a meta tag or with [HTTP X-Robots-Tag](http://robots-txt.com/x-robots-tag/).